# Requirements of python decorators?

Tags: python, function, decorator

I've been trying to understand decorators. I had understood them as a function that you pass other functions through, to modify some functionality. However, the following type error is returned. Could someone explain (A) Why this is not valid? and (B) How this code should be modified such that 12 is returned?

```py
def dec(x):
    return 2*x

@dec
def func(x,y):
    return x*y

>>>
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-355f941cfec0> in <module>
      3 
      4 @dec
----> 5 def func(x,y):
      6     return x*y
      7 

<ipython-input-89-355f941cfec0> in dec(x)
      1 def dec(x):
----> 2     return 2*x
      3 
      4 @dec
      5 def func(x,y):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'
```

Comment: ``x`` in ``dec`` is the function object ``func``. And that's what the error is telling you: ``2 * func`` cannot be computed.

Comment: Your decorator should take a callable as an argument and generally *return a callable*. Your "decorator" expects a number, presumabbly, because all it does with it's argument is `2*x`. Well, when you do `@dec` over your function definition, it passes the function as the `x` argument, hence the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function'` since you cannot multiply a function object by an int object

Comment: If your intention is for the decorated functions to return twice the values that they would have if undecorated, you should have the decorator define some function `g` which returns `2*f(*args)`, and then have the decorator return this function `g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator is given a function as an argument and needs to return a function, not a value. For example:

```
def dec(fn):
  def newfn(x, y):
    return 2 * fn(x, y)
  return newfn
```

The point is that I am returning a **function** that if called will call fn internally, multiply that result by two and return that.

A decorator replaces one function with another. So this:

```
@dec
def mult(x, y):
  return x * y
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
def mult(x, y):
  return x * y
mult = dec(mult)
```

In both cases I am replacing mult with whatever the function dec(mult) returns. The decorator syntax is just a convenience to express that. If dec doesn't return a function then I am going to get an error when I try to call mult.

```
>>> def dec(fn):
...   return 12
...
>>> @dec
... def mult(x, y):
...   return x * y
...
>>> mult
12
>>> mult(9, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>
```

mult is 12 so that last line is "12(9, 5)" and 12 is not a callable function, hence TypeError.

Comment: So as a general rule, a decorator should always have a nested function? Otherwise I'd experience similar errors

Comment: I expanded my reply to explain this... the decorator can return anything you like, but remember you're *replacing* the original function with whatever the decorator returns. It doesn't have to be a nested function, but it does have to be a function.